# Multiplication of projection matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A$ and $B$ be two projection matrices having same dimensions. Then does the following hold
\begin{equation}
AB\leq I,
\end{equation}
where $I$ is the identity matrix. In other words is it true that $I-AB$ is positive semi-definite.

Comment: Component entries are less than or equal to those in I? Or the eigenvalues of $AB$ are less than or equal to one? Or...??

Comment: @StefanSmith: If $A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{bmatrix}\frac12&\frac12\\\frac12&\frac12\end{bmatrix}$, then you'll see they don't (and I've deleted my comment :-) Sorry for the confusion, I was not including the requirement for symmetry in positive semi-definite.

Comment: @robjohn : thanks.  I just discovered almost the same counterexample myself.

Comment: I assume you are talking about (orthognal) projections, ie self-adjoint idempotents $A,B$. Then the first requirement for $AB\leq I$ to make sense is that $AB$ be self-adjoint, which in this case is equivalent to $AB=BA$. Then it is not hard to see that $AB$ is again a projection, whence $\leq 1$.

Comment: @julien : Thanks.  I removed my comment containing the assertion that "orthogonal projection matrices commute", because that assertion is false.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you mean by matrix inequality, but assuming you mean an inequality componentwise, it's clearly false, for instance let

$$A = B = \frac{1}{2} \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 1\\1 &1\end{array}\right]$$
be projection onto the vector $(1,1)$.

Then $AB = A$ has positive off-diagonal entries so violates your inequality.

EDIT: $(I-AB)$ is not positive semi-definite, as projection matrices are not in general symmetric. For instance
$$A = \left[\begin{array}{cc}1 & 2\\0 & 0\end{array}\right]$$
is a projection matrix ($A^2 = A$) but $I - A^2 = I-A$ is clearly not symmetric.

Comment: By $I \geq AB$,I mean to say that $(I-AB)$ is positive semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

Another answer here shows $AB$ need not be symmetric, so the answer is "no".  But even if you use some nonstandard definition of "positive semidefinite" that doesn't require symmetry, the answer is still no.

Let $n=2$, $A=I$, and $B=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$.  Let $\mathbf{x}=\begin{bmatrix}-1\\2\end{bmatrix}$.  Then
$$
\mathbf{x}^T(I-AB)\mathbf{x}=\mathbf{x}^T(I-B)\mathbf{x}=-1<0
$$

But if $A$ and $B$ is are both *orthogonal* projection matrices ($A^2=A=A^T$ and $B^2=B=B^T$), then, while $AB$ is probably not symmetric, it can be shown that $\|AB\mathbf{x}\| \leq \|\mathbf{x}\|$ for any column vector $\mathbf{x}$ of the right length, where $\|\cdot\|$ is Euclidean norm, so
 $\|\mathbf{x}\|^2 = \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} \geq \|\mathbf{x}\|\|AB\mathbf{x}\|$, and
$\mathbf{x}^T(I-AB)\mathbf{x} \geq 0$.

Comment: @robjohn : Thanks, you found a mistake in my answer.  What I claimed was true for orthogonal projection matrices (with $P^T = P$) but false for arbitrary projection matrices (with just $P^2 = P$).  I'll fix my answer.

Comment: I latexified your matrices. Make sure I got them right.

Comment: @robjohn : Thanks a lot.  You really didn't have to do that. They're right.